# The website width changed in mobile

Tags: css, sass, materialize

Hi my website width doesn't show up normally in mobile, so the website looks too small. The normal width is supposed to be 375, but it become 980. I have no idea why? since I only use materialize and my SCSS doesn't hard code any width. I don't have any clue to get start. Wish to get some help. Thank you.

[image: My website]
[image: A sample website]

```
    .brand-logo {
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.YellowtailLogo {
    font-family: 'Yellowtail', cursive;
}
.brand-logo img{
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    top: 3px;
}

.h1Landing {
    font-family: 'Yellowtail', cursive;
    color: #ee6e73;
}

.msg_page_container {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;

    .collection {
      overflow: scroll;
      height: 40%;
    }

    .msg_input_div{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use media query to change content-width to width of mobile screen:

```
@media screen and(max-width:375px){
html,body{width:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
}
```

and include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in CSS

Comment: You are missing a }

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you. it is so important and basic. I couldn't find a right key word to search solutions. Now I see. :-)